# Laravel DB::statement / DB::update not working but I do get the amount of "altered" rows returned

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have the following (simple) code. If I copy / paste the queries, they run just fine.

Things I have checked:

- The DB users has all the correct permissions to do this alteration
- The DB connection is the correct one

The weird thing is, I do get returned the amount of "updated" rows.

I have tried the following formats (all do not work):

```
$activatedCatIds = DB::update('UPDATE offline_mall_categories SET deleted_at=NULL WHERE id IN (SELECT category_id FROM offline_mall_category_product GROUP BY category_id)');
$deletedCatids = DB::update('UPDATE offline_mall_categories SET deleted_at=NOW() WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT category_id FROM offline_mall_category_product GROUP BY category_id) AND deleted_at IS NULL');
echo "IN TOTAL " . $activatedCatIds . " CATEGORIES WERE ACTIVATED. AND " . $deletedCatids . " WERE DELETED" . PHP_EOL;
```

Does return the amount of rows updated. But no changes are happening in the DB.

I try the following format:

```
$existingCats = DB::connection()->getPdo()->query('SELECT category_id FROM offline_mall_category_product GROUP BY category_id')->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$activatedCatIds = Category::whereIn('id', $existingCats)->restore(); // restore any deleted cats.
$deletedCatids = Category::whereNotIn('id', $existingCats)->delete();
echo "IN TOTAL " . $activatedCatIds . " CATEGORIES WERE ACTIVATED. AND " . $deletedCatids . " WERE DELETED" . PHP_EOL;
```

The same story. "Altered rows is filled in", but no changes happening.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: _Silly Question First ... Sorry_ Are you sure you are checking the same database that the code is applying changes to?

Comment: I do have 2 connections going. But by not specifying a connection, it should go to the default one (the rest of the script it does that fine). I am sure I am checking the correct DB though.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 options here:

1. You are **checking wrong database** - so records are really deleted but in other database
2. You are using **database transactions**. So you update rows, but before finishing transaction some exception is thrown and changes are not persisted in database.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is not the case for both. 5 lines above these queries, I call DB::statement('UPDATE offline_mall_categories SET deleted_at=NULL'); -> And this edit does come through.
I am also not using transactions or have any errors. If I put these statements in a try catch block no errors get thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by running:

```
DB::reconnect('mysql');
```

Before calling my queries. Apparently somewhere along the lines Laravel forgets my connection?

Not satisfied with this solution, but does seem to fix it for now.

Answer (score 0):

DB::connection('DB1')->update("UPDATE TABLE t1 SET t1.column_name = (SELECT column_name FROM DB2.TABLE2 t2 WHERE t1.primary_id = t2.foriegn_id)");

In my case on Oracle SQL. Remember DB::beingTranstion() need to remove.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).